# How to group elements in a dataframe by a specific element number in R?

Tags: r, data-science

I want to group the output of this dataframe into the maximum of values starting from each 0.

For example, the first group would be [0,221,551,...,2356]

Each grouping is to be added, if that helps!

> print(without_Errors2$timeRelativeToTrialStart)

```
[1] 0   221   551   771   991  1154  1392  1596  1830  2041  2365     0   309   539   747   992  1198  1471  1681  1911  2129  2391     0   243   527   742   958  1207
[29]  1473  1671  1934  2188  2469     0   239
```

Comment: This is sorting the data by first the grouping column, then your time column. = `without_Errors2[order(without_Errors2$grouping_column, without_Errors2$timeRelativeToTrialStart), ]`

Comment: If you don't have a grouping column, create one with `without_Errors2$grouper = cumsum(without_Errors2$timeRelativeToTrialStart == 0)`

Comment: And if you need more help than that, or your intent is different, please edit your question to include sample input in a copy/pasteable way and desired output. `dput()` is best for sharing inputs, e.g., `dput(without_Errors2[1:20, c("timeRelativeToTrialStart", "other_relevant_column")])`.